# Can I use WIF to authenticate on services like Gmail and Hotmail?

Tags: c#, gmail, wif, hotmail

Can Windows Identity Foundation allow us to connect to services and read contact information?

Here is a idea of how WIF advantages:

- WIF externalizes authentication,
  passing it over to security token
  services (STS) and reducing the
  demands on individual developers
- WIF
  also supports trust relationships
  where a service trusts anyone
  authenticated by the application
  accessing it.
- WIF provides support
  for a single sign-on (SSO) for users
  by sharing STS among applications.
- Developers can also, at run time,
  support both by creating a trust
  relationship between the application
  and service or bypassing the user's
  credentials from the application to
  the service.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do, the answer is Yes.

Using Azure ACS federated to WIF e.g., you can connect to Facebook and get all the Facebook user attributes that you have asked for (provided that the user agrees during login to provide them). You can also connect to Google.

Or you can write your own custom STS federated to WIF that has some kind of interface on the other side that invokes a service and passes the details through e.g. using DotNetOpenAuth to handle the OpenID protocol. See [StarterSTS](http://startersts.codeplex.com/) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Watch [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Interoperability/Identity-Mash-up-Federation-Demo-using-Multiple-Protocols-OpenID-and-WS-Federation) as a starting point. There is a link for the source code and documentation, so you can see if the direction fulfils your needs.

Comment: it is pretty interesting, regarding the no account creation on your website. You just have to use a sort of existing third party ID. But do we have to confirm the disclosure everytime we login??

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here?

Comment: if you see the video, you notice that paypal account disclosure form appears each time user visit "medtronic" website page